# Cсылка на определенную страницу из push уведомления android intel xdk

Tags: android, html5, cordova

Как можно сделать push уведомление через GMC с ссылкой на определенную страницу в приложении написанном на HTML5, cordova?

Comment: Вот на хабрахабре рассматривали push уведомления https://habrahabr.ru/post/274169/